# change value array angularJS before POST to API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an array :

```
[{"IDAlokasiEmiten":154,"IDOrganization":12,"NamaOrganization":null,"CodeEmiten":"ANTM","NameEmiten":"AAneka Tambang (Persero) Tbk"},{"IDAlokasiEmiten":0,"IDOrganization":null,"NamaOrganization":null,"CodeEmiten":"ADHI","NameEmiten":"Adhi Karya (Persero) Tbk"}]
```

How do I change some values before I post to API?

I want POST to API into:

```
[{"IDAlokasiEmiten":0,"IDOrganization":12,"NamaOrganization":null,"CodeEmiten":"ANTM","NameEmiten":"AAneka Tambang (Persero) Tbk"},{"IDAlokasiEmiten":0,"IDOrganization":12,"NamaOrganization":null,"CodeEmiten":"ADHI","NameEmiten":"Adhi Karya (Persero) Tbk"}]
```

Here is my AngularJS:

```
// GET Detail Alokasi Emiten
    $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten = [];
    $scope.addItemAlokasi = function () {
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.push({
            IDAlokasiEmiten: 0,
            IDOrganization: 12,
            NamaOrganization: '',
            CodeEmiten: $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.CodeEmiten,
            NameEmiten: $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.NameEmiten
        });
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.IDAlokasiEmiten = '';
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.IDOrganization = '';
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.NamaOrganization = '';
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.CodeEmiten = '';
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.NameEmiten = ''
    };
    $scope.resetForm = function () {
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.IDAlokasiEmiten = ''; 
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.IDOrganization = '';
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.NamaOrganization = '';
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.CodeEmiten = '';
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.NameEmiten = ''
    };
    $scope.deleteItem = function (index) {
        $scope.emit.detailDaftarEmiten.splice(index, 1);
    };
    $scope.getTotalItems = function () {
        return $scope.detailDaftarEmiten.length;
    };
```

But it doesn't work :(

I want to set all value array for (`IDAlokasiEmiten=0` and `IDOrganization=12`).

Answer (score 0):

While you raising the post request you keep your array data (your desired data) in the body of post request.for an example:
http.post(url,{(your data(key-ordered pair)})
Which returns the promises from the promises you will access the results.
.  Hope its helpfull